# Reusing subject in reply message with mailboxer - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a gem called [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) to allow users to send messages among eachother.

For the reply to message method, is there a way I can get the user to skip putting in a new subject every time they reply in a conversation??

In my conversations controller, this is what I had:

```
  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
    redirect_to conversation
  end
```

I tried using:

```
 def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_reply))
    redirect_to conversation
  end
```

Which has not worked. Ideally there should only be one subject per conversation, I'm not sure why this gem would allow a different subject in every response within a conversation. How do I remove the subject from reply's so that the message keeps the same subject the entire time? Should I modify the reply method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like if there is no subject passed to `reply_to_conversation`, the subject is set to `"RE: {conversation.subject}"`, where `conversation` is the first argument passed to `reply_to_conversation`.

So one solution is to just not pass a subject argument to this method, e.g.:

```
current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, body)
```

If you really want it to just copy the subject (with no "RE:"), you would do:

```
current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, body, conversation.subject)
```

The source for this method should help:

https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb

Comment: Should be able to call `sender` on each message in the conversation, e.g. `conversation.messages.each {|m| puts #{m.sender}/n"}` would print out a list of sender id's. I'm just postulating after looking at the code; I've never actually used this gem.

Comment: Hey Steve! Can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417119/ordering-messages-in-converation-rails